# Performing calculation on each array element

Tags: php

I have this array called `$addon_array`, that when i use var_dump shows up like this

```
array(10) { 
    ["ext_token"]=> string(5) "floor"  
    ["ext_token_child"]=> string(6) "carpet"  
    ["concrete"]=> string(1) "4"  
    ["cement"]=> string(1) "3"  
    ["sand"]=> string(1) "2"  
    ["wood_4_2"]=> string(1) "4"  
    ["wood_8_2"]=> string(1) "2"  
    [0]=> string(0) ""  
    ["brick"]=> string(3) "100"  
    ["carpet"]=> string(1) "3"
}
```

What I have bee trying to do most of the night is try and figure a way of cycling through all the different elements of the array (except `ext_token` and `ext_token_child`) and multiply each number via another variable called `$qty` (which can be anything, it doesn't matter).

Then I want them put in a new array again along with their corresponding `columnNames` (`cement` or `sand` etc...)
I think it is jsut the simple case of just performing a foreach loop on each element, but I can't seem to be able to put them back into a new array.

Thanks for any and all help

Comment: What does this have to do with mysql or ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($addon_array as $key => $col) {
  if($key == 'ext_token' || $key == 'ext_token_child') {
    $new_array[$key] = $col;
  } else {
    $new_array[$key] = $col * $qty;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok brilliant, that looks good, what i will do though, is only add the elements that have the calculation performed on them added to the array, so for example ext_token and ext_toke_child, i would not add to the array, so would i just remove the $new_array[$key] = $col? Also, i just noticed i have a blank element in my array with no variables, how would i not perform a calculation on this? Thanks

Comment: @Arken Yah, remove that line, then invert the meaning of the if statement so it only runs on valid values. For the blank one either check for blank: `$col === ''` (Note the three equals - this is VERY important). Or use `is_numeric($col)` and automatically check if it's a number - then you don't even need to check for `ext_token` since it's not a number.

Comment: Ok briliant, i just checked now and it works great, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

This should work (using [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk)):

```
$new_array = array_walk($addon_array, function($v, $k) use ($qty) {
  if(in_array($k, array('ext_token', 'ext_token_child'))) return $v;
  return $v*$qty;
});
```

Comment: @Arken This version is a bit nicer since the array loop runs internally. But it's harder to understand for a newbie than mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$qty = 10;
$newArray = array();
foreach($addon_array as $key => $val){
    if($key != 'ext_token' && $key != 'ext_token_child'){
        $newArray[$key]    = $qty*(int)$val;
    }
}

$newArray['ext_token'] = $addon_array['ext_token'];
$newArray['ext_token_child'] = $addon_array['ext_token_child'];

var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cycling through array in PHP is quite simple, use foreach.

```
$new = array();
foreach($addon_array as $key=>$value){

     if($key != "ext_token" OR $key != "ext_token_child"){
          $value = $value*$qty;
     }
     $new[$key] = $value;
}
```